# Angular 8 template driven form - pass controls using ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I know this's been asked many times before. But I cannot find a solution that works for me.

I have a template driven form with a control which marked as required and passed via ngTemplateOutlet.
Form is valid even when I don't have value on the control.

Tried all possible

```
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
```

AND

```
  viewProviders: [{
       provide: ControlContainer,
       useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
       deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
       }]
```

but no luck

If you could make this Stackbliz work, that would be awesome

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xm3nf7

Note: I cannot put the template inside the form as there are other parts accessing it.

Comment: Well this cloud be an angular bug or feature, because angular is not even updating the form's controls. But a work around is with reactive forms.

Answer (score 1):

I Supouse your form don't know about the ngModel of the ngTemplate. A work arround is using ViewChildren to check all the NgModels in the pages are valid or not. see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr2bbm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
@ViewChildren(NgControl) list: QueryList<NgControl>;
  lastName: string;
  yet=false
  get invalid() {
    let invalid = false;
    if (this.list) {
      this.list.forEach(x => {
        invalid = invalid || x.invalid
      })
    }
    return invalid
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.yet=true
    })
  }

<button [disabled]="yet && invalid"  (click)="actionConfirmed()"> Confirm  </button>
```

NOTE the "strange" yet is to avoid AfterChecked error

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I would like to know if there's a proper solution to this. ie; to make the form know about its containing controls. In my application I have another ng-template which contributes another control to this form from a child component.

Comment: +1 for the clever workaround to Changed after Checked errors.  What is happening to cause those errors in the first place though?  Usually it's a sign of a faulty design with changes being caused during recalculation.